# The problem of generating baccarat roadmap in node.js

Tags: javascript, json

I encountered problem when calculating the baccarat BigEye roadmap.

I got the baccarat game result, the result looks like this:

```
let BaccaratResult= [
    {"id": 10, "bw": 1, "pw": 0, "tie": 0},
    {"id": 11, "bw": 1, "pw": 0, "tie": 0},
    {"id": 12, "bw": 0, "pw": 1, "tie": 0},
    {"id": 13, "bw": 0, "pw": 1, "tie": 0},
    {"id": 14, "bw": 0, "pw": 0, "tie": 1},
    {"id": 15, "bw": 0, "pw": 1, "tie": 0},
    {"id": 16, "bw": 0, "pw": 1, "tie": 0},
    {"id": 17, "bw": 0, "pw": 0, "tie": 1},
    {"id": 18, "bw": 0, "pw": 1, "tie": 0},
    {"id": 19, "bw": 1, "pw": 0, "tie": 0},
    {"id": 20, "bw": 0, "pw": 1, "tie": 0},
];
```

bw stands for banker win.
pw stands for player win.
tie stands for Tie.

Current Baccarat Roadmap (according to BaccaratResult above)
[image]

An Example of Baccarat Roadmap

[image]

[Baccarat Roadmap Rules](https://www.livedealer.org/the-baccarat-roadmap-manual/)

where the rules are difficult

[image]

At present, I have completed the roadmap data of Big Eye Road.

[Here is my code](http://tpcg.io/_C7ZL02)

Here is the output：

```
{
  "BigRoad": {
    "col1": {
      "bw": 2
    },
    "col2": {
      "pw": 5,
      "tie": [
        2,
        4
      ]
    },
    "col3": {
      "bw": 1
    },
    "col4": {
      "pw": 1
    }
  }
}
```

The description is on the BigRoad (refer to the picture of the current baccarat roadmap)

The first column is the record that the banker won 2 times.

The second column is the record that player has won 5 times, and the 2nd and 4th player have a draw behind the player.

The third column has a record of the banker winning 1 time.

The fourth column is the record of the player winning 1 time.

Now I hope to complete the data of Big Eye Road, but this rule is completely clueless to me.

The BigEyeRoad data needs to be generated based on the results of the BigRoad, which is very difficult for me...

This is the result I expected:(The results are in the Current Baccarat Roadmap image)

```
{
    "BigEyeRoad":{
        "col1":{
            "red":1
        },
        "col2":{
            "blue":1
        },
        "col3":{
            "red":2
        },
        "col4":{
            "blue":2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt HERE AT SO, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry for the problem, thank you for your help